# Ideas to make a transparent image smaller?

Tags: image, png

My header image, embedded as a png because of the transparency needed for it, at my site http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/ , is the largest thing being downloaded, at 197 kb. Any suggestions on shrinking its size considerably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really compress it too much- It's a "confusing" image, as in, it's not easy to compress in a lossless format because there's no obvious patterns or clear rectangles of color. You COULD split it into about 3 images as it is sometimes a little faster to download that way. Regardless, 200kb isn't that much these days, and it's cached, so it's not too much of a concern.

Comment: If it wasn't for the transparency, well, and its shape, I could make it a jpg. I thought about making a jpg of the parchment background layer with the header embedded on it already, but then I will have to lay out the repeating parchment strips again, so that they match seamlessly, which is a pain. I don't think it is worth my time to do that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Np. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but it is the answer, so could you accept? :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) to reduce color depth and then [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) to apply maximum compression.

If you're not on a Mac, then [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.org) and pnggauntlet will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not much to do, really. If you posterize it to 32 levels and save with maximum compression (eg with XnView) you get 121kb, but with some degradation.

You might also try [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)

I've been experimenting with lossy png compression, inside my PNGJ library, but it's not yet really usable - in case you're interested, here's a result at 95kb http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/9659/1775headerwithimagebw37.png

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the compressed version. Too bad it is so grainy along the edge lines. But I appreciate the info.